# Button won't unhide

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I can get my buttons to hide, **but not unhide**.

I **hide the `answerOneCover`** button on tap with:

```
@IBAction func answerOneCoverTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    animateButtonCoverOut(button: answerOneCover)
}

func animateButtonCoverOut(button: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options:
        UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            button.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { finished in
        button.isHidden = true
    })
}
```

And I try to **unhide the `answerOneCover` button when a different button, `answerOneButtonText` button is tapped**:

```
@IBAction func answerOneButtonTextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    answerOneCover.isHidden = false
}
```

But I can't get `answerOneCover` to unhide.  Is there any way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the buttons **Alpha** back to **1**. change your code to look like this:

```
@IBAction func answerOneButtonTextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    answerOneCover.alpha = 1
    answerOneCover.isHidden = false
}
```

**OR** you can put it in your animations completion like so:

```
func animateButtonCoverOut(button: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options:
        UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            button.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { finished in
        button.isHidden = true
        button.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

Comment: Another option is to never use `isHidden`. Just set the `alpha` as needed.